# Visual Studio 2008 locks dll files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Imagine we have two project A and B.
Project B output is dll in C:\Proj_B.
Project A in csproj file use Task from proj B assembly:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="Task_B" AssemplyFile="C:\Proj_B\B.dll" />
```

Now, after compiling project A, VS2008 lock "C:\Proj_B\B.dll" file untill VS2008 closing, so i coudn't compile project B, because file is locked. Any ideas resolve this?

PS: Locker process devenv.exe found by ProcessExplorer

PS2: Compiling via MSBUILD is fine, VS compiling cause this problem

Comment: I think you should try to find out whether those task frees ddl after usage

Comment: No they are locked, even if i close project untill VS is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is normal behaviour.

VS loads dll's into own AppDomain so they can be releasing only after closing VS.

Strange, but true..

Answer (score 0):

It kind of makes sense that an assembly used by Visual Studio to build would be locked. Typically, you would separate these types of assemblies into their own solution file.  Then build these individually and then only reference the built dll.  So, in your example, Project A and Project B would not be in the same solution.

Or better yet, wrap your tasks in a nuget package.

Then, you break the dependence by not needing to build the task assemblies each time.  This technique can be awkward at first because you are typically changing Project B a lot.  However, build tasks tend to settle quite quickly and are usually not edited nearly as much as code that consumes them.

Comment: Project A and Project B in diff solutions, but i still need connect projects way i am described upper. Can anyone describe why this happen? VS loads dll in VS process AppDomain or smth?